# X-Backside-Transport Header

Tags: java, php, rest, curl, soap

I'm sending a request to an API and this is my response header which i can't really make sense of. I've contacted the team that designed the api and they said everything is fine from their side. I've doubled checked the request body with them, seems fine. I don't know if i'm doing anything wrong and what I'm doing wrong. It's just a normal post request :( . Thank You

```
Method: =============== POST===================

=====================REQUEST HEADER===================
<pre>Array
(
    [Content-Type] => application/json
    [Accept] => application/json
)
</pre>

=====================RESPONSE HEADER===================
<pre>Array
(
    [X-Backside-Transport] => FAIL FAIL,FAIL FAIL
    [Connection] => Keep-Alive
    [Transfer-Encoding] => chunked
    [X-Content-Type-Options] => nosniff
    [X-XSS-Protection] => 1; mode=block
    [Cache-Control] => no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    [Pragma] => no-cache
    [Expires] => 0
    [Strict-Transport-Security] => max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
    [X-Application-Context] => application:sit:8400
    [Content-Type] => application/json;charset=UTF-8
    [Date] => Mon, 09 Oct 2017 15:34:34 GMT
    [X-Client-IP] => 10.72.74.24,87.242.168.254
    [X-Global-Transaction-ID] => 11360487
    [X-Archived-Client-IP] => 10.72.74.24
)
</pre>
```

Comment: What response code are you getting? And why do you think `X-Backside-Transport` is problem?

Comment: @Himanshu Bhardwaj response code is 400. I don't think X-Backside_Transport is the problem, it's just the header i really don't understand. I'm thinking if i can get a scenerio for which that header is returned, and i can use that to find my fault

Comment: Read a bit on this header. It has something to do with IBM WebSphere DataPower. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953782/what-does-x-backside-transport-header-do and http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21498899

Comment: I would recommend testing the API with a simple client like Postman first to see what happens. Do you ever get a `200` and then check with server team to nail down the fault.

Comment: @Himanshu Bhardwaj Alright, i 'll do the post man testing now after i go through the links.. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @BadmusTaofeeq Did you ever resolve this?  I'm getting a 500 error from an IBM server with the same `X-Backside-Transport: FAIL, FAIL` header

Comment: @BadmusTaofeeq- Please post the answer if this was resolved. There are people who are still looking out for the answers.